# android translateanimation in pixels, button disappears

Tags: android, pixel, translate-animation

I'm trying to use a simple translation in which I have a button and I want to move it to a position where another button is. The thing is the button just disappears from the screen right away when the translation starts, it doesn't even move.

my code:

```
Button poli1 = checkPosPoli1();

             TranslateAnimation animpoli1 = new TranslateAnimation(checkPosPoli1().getLeft(),checkBtn().getLeft() , checkPosPoli1().getTop(), checkBtn().getTop());
             animpoli1.setDuration(10000);
             animpoli1.setFillAfter( true );
             poli1.startAnimation(animpoli1);
```

Both checkPosPoli1() and checkBtn return a button and I have printed both their values in console and it's ok.

Comment: I would say that the button is moving to the correct location, just that it is under the other button.

Comment: kindly post your layout, if your on button is inside a layout than button only moves till the extent of the layout it is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation of TranslateAnimation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html . The constructor you are using is this one: `TranslateAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)` which means you want the first and third parameters to be 0 if the view is already in its starting position otherwise you are moving the view way off right at the beginning of the animation.

`TranslateAnimation animpoli1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, targetX - currentX, 0, targetY - currentY);`

if you want it to be relative to the parent, you can use the second constructor:

`TranslateAnimation animpoli1 = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, currentX, targetX, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, currentY, targetY);`